# Trying to create button using arrow

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a button with an arrow same as the below image:

[image]

But when I do that using the below code it looks like this:

[image]

My Code:

```css
.ms-btn,
.ms-btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #3E5B73;
  color: #3E5B73;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 16px 28px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.ms-btn:before {
  content: url(../img/image-left.svg);
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 23%;
  /*background: #fff;*/
  padding: 5px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}
```

```html
<a class="ms-btn" href="">LEARN MORE</a>
```

Hope to see any solution for it using css. so button borders can cut or something..

Comment: Why did you remove the white background from the SVG? That would seem to be what is required to create a visual break in the border.

Comment: Hi, @AHaworth Thanks for your reply. Actually I removed the white background because there are many more sections that have different background colors.

Comment: In that case you could use a css variable to set the background color for each of those secsions. e.g. --bg: #fff; and then use var(--bg) rather than #fff in the pseudo element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to you code the background-color for the 'svg' and adjust the position top. that was it.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
.ms-btn,
.ms-btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #3E5B73;
  color: #3E5B73;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 16px 28px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.ms-btn:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjQiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJldmVub2RkIiBjbGlwLXJ1bGU9ImV2ZW5vZGQiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yMS44ODMgMTJsLTcuNTI3IDYuMjM1LjY0NC43NjUgOS03LjUyMS05LTcuNDc5LS42NDUuNzY0IDcuNTI5IDYuMjM2aC0yMS44ODR2MWgyMS44ODN6Ii8+PC9zdmc+');
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 15%;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="ms-btn" href="">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't add background color because there are some other sections that have different background colors. 

so that way I have to create a button for every section using different background colors.

Comment: @Mak But you need either a background color or a graphic with a corresponding background colour. How many different background colors are we talking about? 
You can 1) provide several button solutions with corresponding colors. or 2) use a special background class (for example: `bg-white` or `bg-gree`n) to set the background according to the page background colour. of course, this can also be done with javascript, but that would be too much.

Comment: sure I can do that way and actually I did that way but I saw somewhere that we can cut the borders using calc function in CSS. I am checking that solution. The things you told me are already implemented before. but my concern is if we can make a transparent background behind the arrow? or we can cut button corners using CSS? is that possible?

Comment: @Mak i don't know if that's possible. but that would basically be a separate question.

Comment: @Mak welcome. take a look to this example. that goes in the right direction: https://codepen.io/the_human_brian/pen/vOrbBG

Answer (score 1):

Use `clip-path` to cut the border. I have added 2 CSS variables to control the cut area:

```css
.ms-btn {
  --s: 15px;
  --b: 10px;
  
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px;
  color: #3E5B73;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 16px 28px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

/* the border */
.ms-btn:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border: 2px solid #3E5B73;
  border-radius: 40px;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%,0 100%,0 calc(50% + var(--s)),var(--b) calc(50% + var(--s)),var(--b) calc(50% - var(--s)),0 calc(50% - var(--s)));
}

/* the arrow */
.ms-btn:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  background: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a class="ms-btn" href="">LEARN MORE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest style to what you want is that I noted below. I remove left border and reduce top and bottom left border radius. You can increase or decrease them as you want. This arrow doesn't have and doesn't need background color and I think it will solve you problem and meet your need.

```css
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
.ms-btn,
.ms-btn:hover {
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0px;
  border-color: #3E5B73;
  border-style: solid;
  color: #3E5B73;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  border-radius: 20px 40px 40px 20px;
  padding: 16px 28px;
  position: relative;
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}

.ms-btn:before {
  content: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iMjQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjQiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgZmlsbC1ydWxlPSJldmVub2RkIiBjbGlwLXJ1bGU9ImV2ZW5vZGQiPjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0yMS44ODMgMTJsLTcuNTI3IDYuMjM1LjY0NC43NjUgOS03LjUyMS05LTcuNDc5LS42NDUuNzY0IDcuNTI5IDYuMjM2aC0yMS44ODR2MWgyMS44ODN6Ii8+PC9zdmc+');
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: 15%;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 24px;
  display: flex;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  transition: 0.3s all linear;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a class="ms-btn" href="">LEARN MORE</a>
</div>
```